# Redux and Nodejs combination/comparision

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Understood the concepts of Redux and Node theoretically - planning to use one of them? both? not sure - How do they compare to each other ? When creating a new app (using React for Example) - can we use both of them? or one of them should be enough? I am stuck with this question. What should be the criteria here? People with expertise with these technologies, please help.

Comment: Where did you get the idea to compare these two technologies? Nodejs is server side javascript and redux is a state management library. I feel like that's comparing a highway with a bank.

Comment: @azium or indeed an apple and a chair. OP, may I suggest googling "nodejs for beginners" and "redux for beginners".

Answer (score 3):

- [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) is a library for writing server-side logic in javascript.
- [redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) is a library for managing application state, either client-side or server-side.

For example, it is possible to build an application that uses redux to manage its state on the client. This application could then communicate to a server-side api that is built using nodejs. The server-side api could also be managing its local state using redux.

So you can see that the two technologies are not mutually exclusive, it is not nodejs or redux. Instead you can choose to use them for their respective purposes separately or in conjunction.